# Help with iOS authentication using user token, rest/rails, and keychain

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, objective-c, ios

I have a Rails application (irrelevant, I know) and I want to authenticate an iOS app against the Rails app, and persist the authentication so future requests to the Rails API work without re-authenticating each request. Conceptually, here's what I want to do... I'm not sure if this is the best approach, though.

Alright, so in my Rails app each user has a unique token (SHA1 hash). I was thinking the first time the iPhone app is loaded, the user would see a username/password screen. They'd enter their credentials for the Rails app, and upon successful authentication, the Rails app would return their unique user token that could then be stored in the keychain? And from there on out, I was thinking I could simply append the user token to all API requests and that's how I could verify the user within the Rails app. This would also keep the username/password independent of the iPhone app (so the user could change their username/password in the Rails app, but the iPhone app wouldn't care about that since it would be using their token, which would not change).

I thought my URL requests might look something like this:

```
http://example.com/api/v1/[whatever].json?token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Does that sound like a reasonable approach to take? Or are their concerns I'm not aware of with this approach? I've been doing Rails work for a long time, but I'm relatively new to iOS (only have 1 app under my belt, and it didn't require any authentication).

If this is a good approach to take, is it hard to work with the keychain? I think I read that the simulator and the device itself don't support the same API's for keychain access? (or maybe the simulator doesn't support mock keychain access)

Thanks in advance. I tried searching through older posts, but none seem to answer my specific situation.

Comment: Hey mate, just wondering if you ended up with a solution to this, I'm in the same situation now and kinda stuck.

Comment: I'm assuming you just typed http for the example but for other people reading the question/answers, if you're going to include the authentication string in your API requests, you need to be using https or anyone could just watch the requests and then steal your authentication token. The best way to implement this would probably be to use some sort of challenge-response method that generates a new authentication token every time you launch the app. Then the attacker would only have a token valid for X amount of minutes/hours, instead of the challenge (aka private key) that can create tokens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We've used this approach with iOS connecting with Rails apps and haven't had any issues. In your api controllers, just have a before filter that finds your user based on your token, and returns a 401 if it's not valid.

Then, your mobile device knows if it receives a 401, then show the login screen to get a new/valid token. Put that in a connection factory and you'll be good to go.

You can also add it to the header if you want to keep the URLs clean, but I've had no problems with the URL param approach.

Comment: Great, it's good to know this is a reasonable approach. One more question, how did you store the token for secure retrieval later? Is the keychain the most appropriate place to do that? Thanks!

Comment: The keychain is indeed the best place to store this type of data. [`SSKeychain`](https://github.com/soffes/sskeychain">) makes this very easy.

Answer (score 3):

see this: http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/MobileApps.html

Comment: Nice link, couldn't find via normal googling.